# Quick Launch toolbar keeps randomly disappearing (windows 7)

Tags: windows, windows-7, quicklaunch

I am really used to quick launch toolbar from windows XP. When I moved to Windows 7, I replicated this functionality using some of the guides, such as [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/add-the-quick-launch-bar-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/) or [here](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/79401.aspx).

But every now and then it simply disappears and I have to go through the adding process again. It happens approx. once a month. I haven't managed to track anything, what it would be related to (crashes, headaches, windows updates, new program installations...). It seems to me to be completely random.

There is quite a few posts about this issue in the internet, but either the problem is "it always disappears" (like [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/quick-launch-bar-in-windows-7-keeps-disappearing/8e85e5e3-c52b-446c-b727-e3a549d38995) or [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/131711-quick-launch-disappears.html)), or the answer is "add it back like this" ([here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/quick-launch-toolbar-has-disappeared/da0ed90e-a691-43ab-8e85-070700e6c6fa)), or the answer didn't help me (like [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/59677-random-problem-quick-launch-toolbar-disappears.html) or [here](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/139825-windows-7-quick-launch-keeps-disappearing)).

Any idea appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the Language Bar, then recreate the Quick Launch Bar. That should do it. The Language Bar interferes with it.

Comment: OK, this is awkward. I removed the Language Bar and Toolbar didn't disappear for a month. So I thought like "cool, it works". But to be sure, I put the language bar back just to check it was the reason. It was month and half ago and it didn't disappear either. So I don't know. Maybe it helped somehow permanently, or there was some silent windows fix of that. Anyway, I'll accept this as an answer, as it seems to deserve it. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is very present with Win 10. There is many threads about it on MSFT support forum, or some other sites. Unfortunately no one have a solution except disabling the language bar (or removing it from the taskbar).
Personally i have never ever had the problem with Win 7 (order problem maybe once a year, but disapearing no). But since i installed Win 10, the toolbar disapear indeed most of the time. (Recently, it is every time).
So i also disabled the language bar for now. Win 10 include lang icons in the systray but it seems to miss some functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Disabling Windows Maintenance Mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978980).

Comment: I'll try. None of my links are broken though (which is something that could cause things to be disappearing).

Comment: No, it didn't help. Toolbar disappeared after the very first reboot. Thanks for tip though.